# can't reference class from another project of the same solution

Tags: c#

My solution contains several projects including `Commons` and `TerminatorConsole2`. Now I want to refer `Commons.Constants` class from `TerminatorConsole2.Utils.Constants` file:

```
namespace TerminatorConsole2.Utils
{
    class Constants
    {
        public const string MANAGEMENT_CONSOLE_ADDRESS =
            Commons.Constants.USE_EXTRA_WCF_INSTANCE ?
                "net.pipe://localhost/xxx" :
                "net.pipe://localhost";
```

But I receive "Cannot resolve symbol" on "Commons".
Adding "using Commons" doesn't help, I receive same error.

Why one project can not use class from another project of the same solution?

**UPD** Adding `Constants` class. However I already use it from one another project so I think this class is OK:

```
namespace Commons
{

public class Constants
{
    public const int MAX_INSTRUMENTS_NUMBER_IN_SYSTEM = 200;
    public const bool USE_EXTRA_WCF_INSTANCE = true;
}

}
```

Comment: did you add a project reference to the Common project? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jeroenh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20047/jeroenh) correctly answered the question in a comment... I needed to add a reference.

I didn't need to declare the class `public`, since only class which is used should be public. class that "using" doesn't have to be public.

Answer (score 2):

By default the scope of class is internal which mean could be accessed within that assembly Make the class public in order to make it accessible to other assemblies. More about **[access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)** Also make sure you added the reference of assembly you are reffering.

**Change**

```
class Constants
    {
        public const string MANAGEMENT_CONSOLE_ADDRESS =
            Commons.Constants.USE_EXTRA_WCF_INSTANCE ?
                "net.pipe://localhost/xxx" :
                "net.pipe://localhost";
```

**To**

```
public class Constants
    {
        public const string MANAGEMENT_CONSOLE_ADDRESS =
            Commons.Constants.USE_EXTRA_WCF_INSTANCE ?
                "net.pipe://localhost/xxx" :
                "net.pipe://localhost";
```

Comment: is there a difference between the two? I think you missed the `public` class modifier

Comment: here you will find about public and other access modifiers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: i shouldn't declare this class public. i just need to add reference as jeroenh said

Comment: I thought you added reference, Can you access this class in other assembly without making it public?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add `public` to class `Constants`

```
namespace TerminatorConsole2.Utils
{
    public class Constants
    {
        public const string MANAGEMENT_CONSOLE_ADDRESS =
            Commons.Constants.USE_EXTRA_WCF_INSTANCE ?
                "net.pipe://localhost/xxx" :
                "net.pipe://localhost";
    }
 }
```

Comment: did you add the reference to your project - hope you didn't forget that? Is it a console application or web application?