# Namespaces doesn't appear even after adding reference of class library project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I have two projects in my C# Visual Studio solution, and I have `ProjectA` as a reference in `ProjectB`. `ProjectA` shows up with everything I'd expect to see in the Object Browser for `ProjectB`, but it won't let me do `using ProjectA.Blah`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.

Comment: what error do you get BTW?

Comment: Check target framework of projects.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Both projects are .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Comment: @Rahul I don't get an error, it just doesn't let me access the classes. Name "Blah" not found

Comment: Classes should be public to be accessible. If you don't specify public modifier for them, they are internal by default.

Comment: That was it. Stupid mistake

Comment: Agree with @RezaAghaei check that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't reference class from another project of the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758303/cant-reference-class-from-another-project-of-the-same-solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a new class to the project, the default class template creates the class without access modifier:

```
namespace ProjectA
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

[Internal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-and-struct-accessibility) is the default access modifier if no access modifier is specified for your classes. So the class is not visible to other assemblies.

Then in case of not having any public class in a namespace, the namespace will not be shown in IntelliSense.

To be able to see a class of the referenced assembly in the other projects, define the class access modifier as `public`:

```
namespace ProjectA
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

**Note:** Another thing which should be checked in such cases is checking *Target Framework* of the projects. Target frameworks should be compatible.